# Getting JSON information from URL, then putting and organizing JSON into a CSV File

Tags: java, json, csv, url

I need to get JSON information from an API and then populate an excel file(through CSV) with its organized information. The part that confuses me is organizing the data into the excel (CSV) file, the json is only printing on one line. Could I have an example of how to do this? I am very confused.

I have already figured out how to receive the JSON data from the api and also create the csv file, but the json data prints on one line.

I need the file to be organized into columns such as (Name, Date, etc.) and then populate those columns with the corresponding information from the json data.

Thank you.

Comment: You are going to need to translate your JSON into CSV format. This is a manual process where you extract the data that you want to be represented in each row. That being said, there is no code in your question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your JSON looks like this:

```
{"foo":"bar", "baz":"qux"}
```

And you need to turn it into this csv, with a header row:

```
foo,baz
bar,qux
```

The typical way to do it is the following:

1. Call the API, get the JSON response
2. Deserialise the JSON into an object. This can be a POJO, or if your data is simple you might just stick it into a `Map`
3. Serialise the object into CSV and write it to the file system

[jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) provides an excellent JSON processing API, so to do this with Jackson would look something like this:

Create your POJO:

```
public class MyBean { 
    @JsonProperty
    private String foo

    @JsonProperty
    private String baz

}
```

Deserialise the JSON into the `MyBean` class:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
MyBean b = om.readValue(jsonText, MyBean.class)
```

Now you just need to output the CSV text

```
String csv = "foo,baz\n" + b.getFoo() + "," + b.getBaz();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
writer.write(csv);
```

Of course there are much better ways to write out a CSV if you google around a bit.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by POJO? Also what would I do if my JSON is nested like {data:{name:{firstname middlename lastname}}}?

Comment: But thank you for pointing me in the write direction by telling me about jackson!

Comment: POJO = Plain old java object. If the JSON structure is nested then your java objects should just be nested as well. So take the JSON format and create simple java classes that have the same hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

You certainly got a one line json from the API because of minimized json is cheaper than formatted json to be sent.

For getting the information from your json, you can take a look at json-pointer https://www.baeldung.com/json-pointer, which allow you to take specific information from it.

After retrieving all your information, you must construct your csv file with your selected data.

Comment: The fact that the CSV file represented all data on a single line has nothing to do with the cheap way that the JSON was formatted.